# Why is my program directly crashing

Tags: c

```
typedef int score;
typedef struct tnode *ptrtonode;
typedef ptrtonode tree; 
struct tnode{
     score s;
     tree next;
     bool know;
}; 

scanf("%d",&n);
tree t[n];

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&x);
    t[i]->s=x;
    t[i]->next=NULL;
    t[i]->know=false;
}
```

This is a code snippet.

When it runs 't[i]->s=x;', this program will crash.

I do not know why.

Comment: You've got an array of pointers to tnodes, but you're not allocating any memory (any tnodes) for them to point to.  Suggest `typedef struct tnode tree;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this statement only reserves memory space. Since `n` is not defined at the compile time, the content of the array contains trash values.

```
  tree t[n];
```

any access to `t[i]` will cause your program to access a memory location, denoted by the value which exists in `t[i]`, most likely an address of invalid memory location. This causes your crash. In other cases it could cause memory corruption in unrelated parts of the program and produce incorrect results or crash again.

you need to initialize your array elements before accessing it by allocating the node.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&x);
    t[i] = malloc(sizeof(tnode)); // this was missing.
    t[i]->s=x;
    t[i]->next=NULL;
    t[i]->know=false;
}
```

Comment: C99 allows allocating variable length arrays.

Comment: yes, but as far as i know, it does not initialize them.

Comment: i understand,and it is now possible to run

Comment: @Serge, that's true. Your dynamic array will initially contain the garbage on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

`tree` is of type `struct tnode *`. `tree t[n];` declares `t` as an array of `n` pointer to `struct tnode` (`struct tnode *`). You need to allocate memory to these pointers before accessing memory they points to.